# How can I change a scanf("%d",&variable) to receive an argv from the command line in C

Tags: c, gcc, command, scanf, argv

I'm trying to modify a portion of a program which currently takes user input during runtime and saves the response to a reference to a variable and instead make it fetch the response as an argv[] when compiling. I can fetch the response from argv, but i'm not sure how to retain the variable reference functionality.

Here is the original code:

```
printf("\n Enter Variable : ");
scanf("%d",&variable);
```

Output:

PID BURST   ARRIVAL 
 0  0   12
 1  2   4
 2  3   1
 3  4   2
 Enter quantum time : 5

0  2  3  3  7  1  9

Average waiting time = 0.00

Average turn-around = 2.25.

Here is what I have attempted:

```
variable = argv[1];
```

Output:

0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  1

And:

```
&variable = argv[1];
```

Also:

```
(int*)&variable = argv[1];
```

The first attempt compiles and runs with the command line input, but the output from the program is broken/different from the original. The second and third attempts give gcc errors about using & as the left operand. Does anyone know how to mimic the original functionality with argv[] instead of scanf()?

Comment: Using variable=atoi(argv[1]) corrected the output. Thank you klox, John, and luddite for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` is both reading the string and converting it to an integer (the `%d`).  When you use `argv[1]`, you only have the string, but haven't converted it to an integer.  You need to use a function like `atoi` or `strtol`, like:

```
variable = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
```

Or, as @JohnBollinger correctly points out, sscanf also works:

```
sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &variable);
```

Comment: Or `sscanf()` would do the job, too, and perhaps would be easier to integrate into the existing program.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I hope you don't mind that I used that in my answer.

Comment: @PCLuddite, if I had intended to post my own answer, I would not have first leaked my Super-Sekret technique in a comment on someone else's.  Be my guest.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to convert the command line argument to an integer, then I think the functionality you're looking for is in `atoi` or `strtol`. But a near drop-in replacement for `scanf` is `sscanf`, which reads from a string instead of the standard input.

```
sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &variable);
```

The reason your first attempt didn't work is because what you're really doing is converting the `char*` pointer to an integer. It's not actually reading the content of the string. You were seeing the value of the pointer converted to an `int`.

Your other two didn't work because `&variable` is not an lvalue and cannot be assigned to.